# Pinax TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: pinax

i ran into this errors while trying to modify pinax database model

i am using eclipse pydev

i have this error on the pydev

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /
Exception Value: Caught an exception while rendering: (1146, "Table 'test1.announcements_announcement' doesn't exist")

please how do i correct this

UPDATE: i asked this question and left unresolved some months back and you what ran into the bug again this week and typed the error message in google hit the page with the question and unanswered so i think i have to answer it and hope it help someone in the future have the same problem.

some the problem is that the sqlite path is out of place so django or this case pinax can not find it so to resolve that change the absolute path to sqlite like it

DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'    # 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'ado_mssql'.
DATABASE_NAME = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'dev.db' )      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
DATABASE_USER = ''             # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''         # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_HOST = ''             # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PORT = ''             # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.

i hope that help

Comment: So what does your template code look like?

Answer (score 0):

chnge the sqlite3 path like this

DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3' # 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'ado_mssql'. DATABASE_NAME = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'dev.db' ) # Or path to database file if using sqlite3. DATABASE_USER = '' # Not used with sqlite3. DATABASE_PASSWORD = '' # Not used with sqlite3. DATABASE_HOST = '' # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3. DATABASE_PORT = '' # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

If your database model is missing a column, run

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

from the command line.  This ensures that your models match the underlying database representation.